# TwitterBootstrapMVC 3 MVC5 DropDownListFor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-select, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to make a dropdownlist using:

```
@(Html.Bootstrap().DropDownListFor(m=> m.Profession, ViewBag.AllProfessions))
```

To replace the following:

```
<select id="Profession" name="Profession" style="width: 235px; background-color: #FFFFCC;">
      @{List<string> allProfessions = ViewBag.AllProfessions;
        string selectedProfession;}
      @{if (Model != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Profession))
        {selectedProfession = Model.Profession;}
        else {selectedProfession = allProfessions[0];}
       }
       @foreach (var aProfession in allProfessions)
       {
        string selectedTextMark = aProfession == selectedProfession ?  
        "selected=\"selected\"" : String.Empty;
          @Html.Raw(string.Format("<option value=\"{0}\" {1}>{2}</option>", aProfession,
           selectedTextMark, aProfession))
        }
   </select>
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by using regular bootstrap class and it worked.

```
 <select id="Profession" name="Profession" style="width: 344px;" class="form-control  input-sm" >
```

Hope this could help someone.

Comment: @`(`Html.Bootstrap().Html.DropDownList...  
I don't think you need the first `(`